# How to close pyPDF "PdfFileReader" Class file handle

Tags: python, pypdf

this should be very simple question, for which I couldn't find answer by Google search: How to close file handle opened by pyPDF "PdfFileReader" Class

Here is snippet:

```
import os.path
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

fname = 'my.pdf'
input = PdfFileReader(file(fname, "rb"))

os.rename(fname, 'my_renamed.pdf')
```

which raises error [32]

Thanks

Comment: Do you run windows and does `my_renamed.pdf` exist before you are renaming?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I run Windows 7 32 bit and use Python 2.5. File 'my_renamed.pdf' does not exist

Comment: @romor `32` means cannot access the file because it is in use. Try to close `fname` manually (after reading it) and then rename.

Comment: yeah, that's my question - how to close the file :)

Comment: `fd = file(fname, 'rb'); input = PdfFileReader(fd); "read it here"; fd.close(); os.rename(...)`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for, however lame it my seem :D

Comment: @romor: Hi, was your question answered? If so could you close your question?

Answer (score 7):

The operating system is preventing a file from being re-named while something else has it open. This is a Good Thing (tm).

Python's [with](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) statement will automatically close the file after you're done reading/manipulating it.

```
with open(fname, "rb") as f:
  input = PdfFileReader(f, "rb")

os.rename(fname, 'my_renamed.pdf')
```

If you're still on Python 2.5, you'll have to do a special import:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Python 2.6 and above have with enabled by default.

Comment: Hi, @fitzgeraldsteele . I love this answer but `input = PdfFileReader(f, "rb"))` has an extra right parenthesis. Should be `input = PdfFileReader(f, "rb")` .

Comment: Fixed. This answer's been there for over 10 years and no one's noticed, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really *have to* access this from the PdfFileReader object (that is: if you haven't got a reference to the file object yourself), you can use `reader.stream.close()`

Note that the PdfFileReader will need an open file object to access the pdf's content (it doesn't pull everything into memory from the start), so only close the file when you are done with the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest to handle the file open out of the PdfFileReader

Your code will be:

```
import os.path
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

fname = 'my.pdf'
fh = file(fname, "rb")
input = PdfFileReader(fh)

fh.close()
os.rename(fname, 'my_renamed.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

instead using `input=PdfFileReader(file(fname, "rb"))`
create an input stream like this

```
inputStream=file(fname, "rb")
    input=PdfFileReader(inputStream)
```

and when job is done use `inputStream.close()`
then u will be able to call it through os package