# PDFFileReader isn't closing pdf after use

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, win64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close pyPDF “PdfFileReader” Class file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422297/how-to-close-pypdf-pdffilereader-class-file-handle)

I'm running Python 2.7 on Win 64bit.
I'm trying to download a pdf to file, open the pdf, extract the text, and then at the end delete the pdf, but getting an error when I try to delete the python (using the python code and manually trying to delete the pdf - windows says the file is in use by pythonw). My simplified code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf_url = "www.Url for.pdf"

file_path = 'myfile.pdf'
f = file(file_path, 'wb')
f.write(urllib2.urlopen(pdf_url).read())
f.close()

pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_path, 'rb'))

os.remove(file_path)
```

Error returned:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is 
being used by another process: 'myfile.pdf'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Saw that before, didn't work though. The OP's solution was to add "fd.close()" which I have already done. Solution 1 was to add "reader.stream.close()" but I got "NameError: global name 'reader' is not defined" back. Solution 2 gave me "PdfReadError: EOF marker not found"

Comment: In this example you could use `StringIO` instead of creating the file in the first place.